# Why the object is spinning too slow ? And how can I make that the object will face forward original direction when not rotating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void Update()
    {
        if(toRotate == true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * 10);
        }
    }
```

Even changing the speed to 100 it's very slow.
And I want that when not rotating to add else the transform will face forward as default.

This is working for rotating fast :

```
transform.Rotate(0,0,100);
```

This is working for both problems :

```
private void Update()
    {
        if(Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEInteractionManagerScript.naviRotate == true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0,0,100);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of `Time.deltatime`, cause `Time.deltatime` retunrs a diffrance between two consecutive frames which is a very small number if your framerate is high. In my case, FPS is 85 and my deltatime is about 0.0166682.

And is I want to make this number big about 16.6682 then I have to multiply it by **1000**, if I multiply it with **100** I'll only get **1.66682** which is slow rotation speed and at this speed rotation will take **2.54 Sec** to spin this around 360 degrees.

And for the rotation you can just say `transform.localrotation = Quaternion.identity` to set your object's rotation to zero.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example you are using the transform.rotate() in the wrong way. The first argument should indeed be a Vector3(), representing euler angles, but the second argument should be the reference coordinate system for the rotation, Space.Self or Space.World.

If I correctly understand what you are trying to achieve you should use the function like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Stack_rotate : MonoBehaviour

{
     float rotationAngleOverZAxisPerFrame = 1200f;

     void Update()
     {
         transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, rotationAngleOverZAxisPerFrame * Time.deltaTime), Space.Self);
     }
}
```

Rotating objects can be very frustrating because there are multiple ways to specify object rotations in unity.

Comment: Added 'Time.deltaTime' to make the rotation speed frame rate independent.